# How to get R to search a large dataset row by row for presence of values in one of two columns, then return a value when data is missing

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm pretty new to R and am working with a very large dataset of tree growth/mortality over several years. Since mortality was not always recorded correctly I need to search each row for measurements (can be either diameter at breast height (DBH) or diameter at ground height (DGH)) and then, if they stopped prior to the most recent survey, have R record the year in which they stopped so that I can get a count of how many presumed deaths occurred per year. The data frame, which I'm calling `mortality`, is structured like this:

```
year  plant.id  dbh  dgh  
1        1      3.2  na
2        1      3.3  na
3        1      3.5  na
4        1      3.6  na
1        2      na   1.0
2        2      na   1.1
3        2      na   na
4        2      na   na
```

I'd like to be able to add a column or something similar that then gives the year in which a given plant "died", so that it's easy enough to count all the instances of that year in the dataset. Something like this would be great:

```
year  plant.id  dbh  dgh   mort.year
1        1      3.2  na       na
2        1      3.3  na       na
3        1      3.5  na       na
4        1      3.6  na       na
1        2      na   1.0      na
2        2      na   1.1      na
3        2      na   na       3
4        2      na   na       3
1        3      2.2  na       na
2        3      2.3  na       na
3        3      2.4  na       na
4        3      na   na       4
```

This is further complicated by 1) new plants that grew and were then added in later years and 2) occasional instances where a tree was incorrectly considered dead or missing, so measurements were not taken that year, and then in subsequent years the tree was actually found to be alive. The resulting data looks like this:

```
year  plant.id  dbh  dgh
1        4      na   na 
2        4      na   1.0 
3        4      na   1.0 
4        4      na   1.1 
1        5      2.1   na
2        5      na    na
3        5      2.2   na
4        5      2.2   na
```

I basically would like to ignore these for the purposes of mortality estimates (unless they died later on), so the ideal result would be something like this:

```
year  plant.id  dbh  dgh   mort.year
1        4      na   na       na
2        4      na   1.0      na
3        4      na   1.0      na
4        4      na   1.1      na
1        5      2.1   na      na
2        5      na    na      na
3        5      2.2   na      na
4        5      2.2   na      na
```

I know roughly how to get R to count all of the instances of a given year to get the end result, my main challenge is with figuring out what commands/logic I can use to get it to search and then produce a column like that, so any tips/advice on how to do that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `data.table`, which should hopefully be fast:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mortality)
setkey(mortality,plant.id,year)
mortality[, .(mort.year = 
              year[dbh == "na" &
                   dgh == "na" & 
                   cumsum((dbh != "na" | dgh != "na")) == max(cumsum((dbh != "na" | dgh != "na")))]),
                   by = plant.id][,.(mort.year = min(mort.year)), by = plant.id]
   plant.id mort.year
1:        2         3
2:        3         4
```

This works with 3 simple logical comparisons.

1. `dbh == "na"` (note, replace this with `is.na` if the value is `NA` rather than `"na"`)
2. `dgh == "na"`
3. The number of years that a measurement has been observed has to be equal to the maximum number of years that there have ever been a measurement.

Visualizing it may make it easier to understand:

```
 mortality[, temp := cumsum((dbh != "na" | dgh != "na")), by = plant.id][]
    year plant.id dbh dgh temp
 1:    1        1 3.2  na    1
 2:    2        1 3.3  na    2
 3:    3        1 3.5  na    3
 4:    4        1 3.6  na    4
 5:    1        2  na 1.0    1
 6:    2        2  na 1.1    2
 7:    3        2  na  na    2
 8:    4        2  na  na    2
 9:    1        3 2.2  na    1
10:    2        3 2.3  na    2
11:    3        3 2.4  na    3
12:    4        3  na  na    3
13:    1        4  na  na    0
14:    2        4  na 1.0    1
15:    3        4  na 1.0    2
16:    4        4  na 1.1    3
17:    1        5 2.1  na    1
18:    2        5  na  na    1
19:    3        5 2.2  na    2
20:    4        5 2.2  na    3
```

The `min` call has to be separate because of type inconsistencies between `NA` and the double `min` returns.  The `setkey` call insures the years are ordered correctly.

The column can be created with a simple join if necessary:

```
result <- mortality[, .(mort.year = year[dbh == "na" & dgh == "na" & cumsum((dbh != "na" | dgh != "na")) == max(cumsum((dbh != "na" | dgh != "na")))]), by = plant.id][,.(mort.year = min(mort.year)), by = plant.id]

result[mortality,][, mort.year := fifelse(dbh == "na" & dgh == "na", mort.year, NA_integer_)][]
    plant.id mort.year year dbh dgh
 1:        1        NA    1 3.2  na
 2:        1        NA    2 3.3  na
 3:        1        NA    3 3.5  na
 4:        1        NA    4 3.6  na
 5:        2        NA    1  na 1.0
 6:        2        NA    2  na 1.1
 7:        2         3    3  na  na
 8:        2         3    4  na  na
 9:        3        NA    1 2.2  na
10:        3        NA    2 2.3  na
11:        3        NA    3 2.4  na
12:        3         4    4  na  na
13:        4        NA    1  na  na
14:        4        NA    2  na 1.0
15:        4        NA    3  na 1.0
16:        4        NA    4  na 1.1
17:        5        NA    1 2.1  na
18:        5        NA    2  na  na
19:        5        NA    3 2.2  na
20:        5        NA    4 2.2  na
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine your inputs to a single tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
input_tbl <- rbind(read_table(
  "year  plant.id  dbh  dgh   mort.year
1        1      3.2  na       na
2        1      3.3  na       na
3        1      3.5  na       na
4        1      3.6  na       na
1        2      na   1.0      na
2        2      na   1.1      na
3        2      na   na       3
4        2      na   na       3
1        3      2.2  na       na
2        3      2.3  na       na
3        3      2.4  na       na
4        3      na   na       4"
),
read_table(
  "year  plant.id  dbh  dgh   mort.year
1        4      na   na       na
2        4      na   1.0      na
3        4      na   1.0      na
4        4      na   1.1      na
1        5      2.1   na      na
2        5      na    na      na
3        5      2.2   na      na
4        5      2.2   na      na"
)) %>% 
  select(- mort.year)
```

Now let's wrangle

```
outcomes <- input_tbl %>% 
   # Turn na into NA
  mutate(dbh = na_if(dbh, "na"),
         dgh = na_if(dgh, "na"),
   # It's still alive if there's a value in either column
         either = coalesce(dbh,dgh)) %>% 
  select(-dbh, -dgh) %>% 
    # Look at each plant individually
  group_by(plant.id) %>% 
    # Compare it to next year
  mutate(next.ei = lead(either, default = NA),
           # If it has a value this year, and not next year, it looks dead.
         appear.died = !is.na(either) & is.na(next.ei),
           # But no plant is dead if it has a value in the last year.
         alive.end = !is.na(last(either)),
         died = appear.died & ! alive.end)
```

Which is

```
# A tibble: 20 x 7
# Groups:   plant.id [5]
    year plant.id either next.ei appear.died alive.end died 
   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <lgl>       <lgl>     <lgl>
 1     1        1 3.2    3.3     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
 2     2        1 3.3    3.5     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
 3     3        1 3.5    3.6     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
 4     4        1 3.6    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE
 5     1        2 1.0    1.1     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
 6     2        2 1.1    NA      TRUE        FALSE     TRUE 
 7     3        2 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
 8     4        2 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
 9     1        3 2.2    2.3     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
10     2        3 2.3    2.4     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
11     3        3 2.4    NA      TRUE        FALSE     TRUE 
12     4        3 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE
13     1        4 NA     1.0     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
14     2        4 1.0    1.0     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
15     3        4 1.0    1.1     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
16     4        4 1.1    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE
17     1        5 2.1    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE
18     2        5 NA     2.2     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
19     3        5 2.2    2.2     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
20     4        5 2.2    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE
```

Finally, get the deaths:

```
outcomes %>% 
  mutate(mort.yr = ifelse(died, year + 1, NA) ) %>% 
  fill(mort.yr) %>% 
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 20 x 8
    year plant.id either next.ei appear.died alive.end died  mort.yr
   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <lgl>       <lgl>     <lgl>   <dbl>
 1     1        1 3.2    3.3     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
 2     2        1 3.3    3.5     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
 3     3        1 3.5    3.6     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
 4     4        1 3.6    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE      NA
 5     1        2 1.0    1.1     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE      NA
 6     2        2 1.1    NA      TRUE        FALSE     TRUE        3
 7     3        2 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE       3
 8     4        2 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE       3
 9     1        3 2.2    2.3     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE      NA
10     2        3 2.3    2.4     FALSE       FALSE     FALSE      NA
11     3        3 2.4    NA      TRUE        FALSE     TRUE        4
12     4        3 NA     NA      FALSE       FALSE     FALSE       4
13     1        4 NA     1.0     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
14     2        4 1.0    1.0     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
15     3        4 1.0    1.1     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
16     4        4 1.1    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE      NA
17     1        5 2.1    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE      NA
18     2        5 NA     2.2     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
19     3        5 2.2    2.2     FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      NA
20     4        5 2.2    NA      TRUE        TRUE      FALSE      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers seem way more useful, but I worked on this for a bit and wanted to share this `dplyr` approach:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(plant.id) %>% 
  mutate(na_flag = ifelse(dbh == "na" & dgh == "na", 1, 0),
         reborn_flag = 
           case_when(
             any(na_flag > 0) & (year == max(year) & dbh != "na") | (year == max(year) & dgh != "na") ~ "Y",
             TRUE ~ "N"
           ),
         mort.year =
           case_when(
             na_flag == 1 & any(reborn_flag == "Y") ~ 0,
             na_flag == 1 & reborn_flag == "N" & dbh == "na" & dgh == "na" ~ as.numeric(year)
           )) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.),999) %>% 
  mutate(mort.year = 
           case_when(
             mort.year == 999 | mort.year == 0 ~ "na",
             mort.year != 999 ~ as.character(as.numeric(min(mort.year)))
           )) %>% 
  select(-c(na_flag, reborn_flag))
```

Which gives:

```
    year plant.id dbh   dgh   mort.year
   <int>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
 1     1        1 3.2   na    na       
 2     2        1 3.3   na    na       
 3     3        1 3.5   na    na       
 4     4        1 3.6   na    na       
 5     1        2 na    1.0   na       
 6     2        2 na    1.1   na       
 7     3        2 na    na    3        
 8     4        2 na    na    3        
 9     1        3 2.2   na    na       
10     2        3 2.3   na    na       
11     3        3 2.4   na    na       
12     4        3 na    na    4        
13     1        4 na    na    na       
14     2        4 na    1.0   na       
15     3        4 na    1.0   na       
16     4        4 na    1.1   na       
17     1        5 2.1   na    na       
18     2        5 na    na    na       
19     3        5 2.2   na    na       
20     4        5 2.2   na    na
```

Data:

```
df <- data.table::fread('year  plant.id  dbh  dgh  
1        1      3.2  na
2        1      3.3  na
3        1      3.5  na
4        1      3.6  na
1        2      na   1.0
2        2      na   1.1
3        2      na   na
4        2      na   na
1        3      2.2  na       
2        3      2.3  na       
3        3      2.4  na       
4        3      na   na
1        4      na   na 
2        4      na   1.0 
3        4      na   1.0 
4        4      na   1.1 
1        5      2.1   na
2        5      na    na
3        5      2.2   na
4        5      2.2   na')
```